# Очередь функций в iOS

Tags: ios, многопоточность, swift

В программе есть несколько функций, которые обращаются к сайтам с post и get запросами, но в зависимости от запроса они выполняются разное количество времени, иногда одна быстрее другой и наоборот, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы вторая функция выполнялась сразу после выполнения первой. Подскажите, как реализовать подобное, читал про потоки, но не особо разобрался.

**Обновление**

Да, `NSURLRequest`. Просто сначала нужно получить token и куки с сайта, а потом через post запросы получать основные данные. Хотелось бы реализовать "нормальный" код, просто сейчас использую либо таймер, либо циклы, не очень удобно.

Comment: А что используете для обращения? `NSURLRequest` или?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для NSURLRequest проще всего начинать следующий реквест когда получен ответ от предыдущего:

создать реквест:

```
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
```

вы полнить реквесты синхронно (приложение блокируется на время выполнения):

```
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
    // здесь запускать следующий запрос
}
```

асинхронно (выполняется на бэкграунде):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue
       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    //здесь запускать следующий
}];
```

Оба метода `deprecated` в iOS9, новых эпл пока не дал.

Касательно какой метод использовать: я бы предложил всегда использовать асинхронное выполнение. Иногда советуют использовать синхронное для реквестов, где передается/принимается очень мало данных, но при этом пока синхронный реквест выполняется приложение висит (никакие действия от пользователя не обрабатываются), что может привести к плохому user experience при низком уровне сигнала.

Comment: Это именно то, что мне подходит, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать блоки. Например в библиотеке afnetworking есть методы с success блоками. Например метод -

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(id)parameters
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

Запрос который вы хотите использовать первым, используете с этим методом, а второй запрос, помещаете в первый запрос, в success блок.

Comment: Я попробую, спасибо за ответ